# WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/select-editr.list' on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, configuration, text-editor

The first time I ran `sudo apt edit-sources` it prompted me to choose an editor, I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and tried to rerun. Now whenever I run a command that doesn't exist I get this error message:

```
 ~ $ a
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/select-editr.list'

WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/select-editor.list'

a: command not found
```

When I try to run select-editor:

```
 ~ $ select-editor
touch: cannot touch '/home/gib/.selected_editor': Permission denied
 ~ $ sudo select-editor

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/ed
  2. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  3. /usr/bin/vim.basic
  4. /usr/bin/vim.tiny

Choose 1-4 [2]: 3
 ~ $
```

The files are empty:

```
 /etc/apt/sources.list.d $ ll | grep select
-rw-r----- 1 root root   0 May 15 11:54 select-editor.list
-rw-r----- 1 root root   0 May 15 11:54 select-editr.list
```

I'm guessing that the easiest way to fix this would be to put something in those files, though I don't know what.

I have `export EDITOR=$(which vim)` in my .profile.

EDIT:

I checked the location specified in the manual (`man select-editor`), and it seems to be set correctly, but I'm still getting the above error.

```
 ~ $ cat ~/.selected_editor
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim.basic"
```

Comment: Did you read the man pages ?

Comment: My problem is the warnings, not actually setting my default editor. I've edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File a bug @ [Apt Team](http://bugs.debian.org/src:apt)

The Man pages says *edit-sources* is a **WIP**

In the above link there's an *e-mail* and other related links for the **APT** Team.